# FormClosing event is called but nothing happens

Tags: c#

I'm trying to save the file as soon as the form is closed but it does not work properly. It shows the message, but when I tell the program I want to save nothing happens, is as if it executes a return

```
this.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(OverrideEventClosing);

private void OverrideEventClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
 DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Do You Want To Save Your Data", "CodeJuggler", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
 if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes) {
  string myExePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
  System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@ "C:\DB.txt");

  foreach(ListViewItem cliente in listView1.Items) {
   file.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}|{1}|{2}|{3}", cliente.SubItems[0].Text, cliente.SubItems[1].Text, cliente.SubItems[2].Text, cliente.SubItems[3].Text));
  }
 }

}
```

Comment: `e.Cancel = true` will stop the form from closing.

Comment: already removed this line, but nothing happens

Comment: is there an exception thrown?

Comment: no exception!!!

Comment: Are you able to use the debugger? This tool will show you what happens when you run this code.

Comment: Is the problem that the form doesn't close, or that it doesn't save anything? What happens when you don't have the handler _at all_?

Comment: I used try, catch, and checked for an access deny exception. However, I executed as administrator he saved the file but the form was not closed.

Comment: @SharpAlways Perhaps there is another `FormClosing` handler that sets the `e.Cancel` flag? Hard to tell what the problem is because with the information you have provided I cannot reproduce the issue (if you create a whole new application with just a `FormClosing` handler it'd close properly).

Comment: @C.Evenhuis full code > https://pastebin.com/vctKWZrm

Comment: Off topic, but that's not exactly "overriding" the form closing event.  You're just subscribing to it.  Always close your streams.

Comment: I created a new project, and it still does not work. It writes the file but the form remains open.

Comment: You should never write to the root directory.  Windows tries to prevent that.  You aren't using your myExePath variable.

Comment: @LarsTech i tried using two way...

Comment: We can only see the code you post.  And what you've posted doesn't match the "nothing happens" symptom.

Comment: @SharpAlways the code you posted on pastebin still has an `e.Cancel = true;` in it, preventing the form from closing when you click the "Yes" button on the dialog.

Comment: C.Evenhuis sorry for this, its a outdated

Answer (score 2):

Flush and Close stream after write.( after foreach)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with unmanifested line addition

Project > Add New Item > Application Manifest File

[Application Manifest File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nH0R3.png)

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

and using this

```
string myExePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
System.IO.StreamWriter File = new System.IO.StreamWriter(myExePath + @"\item.txt");
```